# How to show only RowDetails (not the row) when a DataGridRow is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, rowdetailstemplate

I got the following `DataGrid`:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding MainText}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DetailText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Assumong `MyList` is a collection of `MyViewModel` objects:

```cs
public class MyViewModel {
    public string MainText { get; set; }
    public string DetailText { get; set; }
}
```

When the user clicks the row the row details are visible. Is it somehow possible to hide the row and only show the details on selection?

Comment: "hide the row and only show the details on selection" -> do you mean somehow replacing the selected line regular template with the `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`?

Comment: I think yes. I want to see only the rowdetails on selection. Not the current row itself with all of the other columns. Just the TextBlock with binding on "SecondTextInList"

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `ControlTemplate` of each `DataGridRow` to hide its main content when it is selected.

You can for example use the `Style` provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates#datagrid-controltemplate-example) by MSDN. This is a big style so I'm only gonna paste important parts here:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <!-- ...some setters... -->
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
          <Border.Background>
              <!-- ... -->
          </Border.Background>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <!-- ...some states... -->
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                    ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"
                                      SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, 
                                                    ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
                                                    Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                               Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                                            ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, 
                                            Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
          </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

The key is to change the `Visibility` of the `DataGridCellsPresenter` to `Visibility.Collapsed` when the `DataGridRow` is selected. You can do it by adding the following `<DataGridCellsPresenter.Style>` markup in the template:

```xml
<DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                        ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
    <DataGridCellsPresenter.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCellsPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCellsPresenter.Style>
</DataGridCellsPresenter>
```

If you test the application again, this will collapse the main content on selected rows, hence only display the detail row.